# Passing an instance of a class into another java file

Tags: java, class, instance, instances

Sorry if this is a stupid question but I'm a little stuck on an issue!

Basically: if i have 3 ".java" files i.e "main.java" , "implement.java" and "class.java"

in class.java I have created a public class

i.e:

```
  public class Inbox {
  int Letters;
  int Bills;
  int Invoices;
  }
```

==============================

In implement.java I created an instance of this class and assigned it variables

i.e:

```
Inbox IX = new Inbox;

IX.Letter = 20;
IX.Bills = 2;
IX.Invoices = 1;
```

==============================

How would I pass these variables (IX.Letters, IX.Bills & IX.Invoices) into my "main.java" ?

I've looked all over the internet but no luck =(

Hope someone can help me

Cheers guys

Comment: Have your compiled your code? Your implement.java has compilation errors.

Comment: class.java should be called Inbox.java due to the class name.

Comment: You have quite a few issues here. Naming of classes (class.java should be inbox.java), usage of getters and setters, and so on. I suggest you read a good book for beginners, or look at tutorials.

Comment: This is just an example I am giving...my code is much larger...The Implement class has an unmarshaler in there so I wanted to leave it secluded. and my main.java is actually a JSwing GUI...and yes I have named the java file after the class...Thanks guys

Comment: Thank you BlackLight...I will look into Getters and Setters...Hopefully that will help

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Eclipse it could generates automatically the getters and setters (souce code > generate getters and setters) it may help you to understand

Comment: Argghh! Im using Netbeans! ='( :@

Comment: Every modern IDE can do that, Netbeans too. Look for it in the menus or google it, you should find it in no time.

Answer (score 0):

This is an example for using getters and setters:

```
public class Inbox {
    private int letters;
    private int bills;
    private int invoices;

    public int getLetters() {
        return letters;
    }

    public void setLetters(int letters) {
        this.letters = letters;
    }
}

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Inbox ib = new Inbox();
        ib.setLetters(20);
        int letters = ib.getLetters();
    }
}
```